# Firebase -How to find the Firebase SDK version and Library I'm using

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to file an issue in the firebase Github repo: [firebase repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues).

This is my first time doing this and 2 of the things that are asked to provide are:

```
Firebase SDK version: _____
Library version: _____
```

[image]

I don't know where to find the Firebase SDK version nor the Library version.

I went to terminal and typed in:

```
firebase -v
firebase -version
```

but neither yielded any results.

How do I find these out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with node, the version of the Firebase Admin SDK you're using is listed in your `package.json` file with the name `firebase-admin`.

Comment: you are correct, thanks. How do I find out the library version I'm using? I can't choose your answer for another 9 minutes

Comment: That is the library. If you find the bug template confusing, feel free to just say so in the bug.

Comment: thanks. I'll choose your answer as the accepted answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: and how to know in flutter??

Answer (score 1):

Searching over your code base with keywords "**firebase version**",
you will find below files which represent your Firebase version.

[image]